# Using method variable inheritance in a class

Tags: python, class, variables, methods, instance

I am trying to understand why we would use classes in Python instead of functions when dealing with data manipulation. I don't understand how a class can help me with my data-manipulation pipeline.

I would like to illustrate with the following dummy code.

```
Class foo():

   def one(self):
   ''' loads data and does something meaningful'''
   self.x = 'eee'
   return self.x

   def two(self):
   '''adds to meaningful data'''
   self.y = self.x + 'fff'
   return self.y

   def three(self):
   '''third process in data pipeline'''
   self.z = self.y + 'ggg'
   return self.z
```

To use the third method `three()` I have to invoke all the other methods as such, because otherwise my instance variables set in `two()` and `one()` are not set.

```
instance = foo()
instance.one()
instance.two()
var = instance.three()
print(var)
>>> 'eeefffggg'
```

Is there another way to make my third method `three()` use the variables that were set in the first two? Why is this more useful than my functional programming (see below), which only needs one line? Should I invoke the methods `one()` and `two()` in my Class in the same way as below?

```
def one():
   return 'eee'

def two():
   x = one()
   return x + 'fff'

def three()
   x = two()
   return x + 'ggg'
```

```
print(three())
>>> 'eeefffggg'
```

How can I build a data-manipulation pipeline within a Class where I simply invoke one method `three()` and it automatically invokes the other two methods and if I want to I can always check on the steps and see the output of methods one and two by calling them? Is this not useful, am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Comment: What about doing the job of one and two in an `__init__`? https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects

Comment: Why don't you call `self.two()` from the `three` method in the same way you call `two()` from the `three` function? But there doesn't seem like any point to the class here.

Comment: Unless you want to pass data implicitly from one function to another (via a class instance), function composition is more important than OOP here.

Comment: This class is a bad use of OO code. Some problems are a great fit for OO code, but not all problems require OO code. So… yeah… if you ain't gonna need it, don't.

Comment: Maybe organize your code so that it makes sense to you now and five years from now.  If you are using the class for composition maybe use a module instead which is the accepted practice for Python code.

Comment: Thanks guys. From what I understand from it is bad practice to use objects in this sense, so I'll just dive into the material a bit deeper to fully understand where it IS very useful.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to understand why we would use classes in Python instead of functions when dealing with data manipulation. I don't understand how a class can help me with my data-manipulation pipeline.

Short answer: this isn't what classes are for. You wouldn't use a wrench when you need a screwdriver, even if it might technically be possible to do so - similar principle here.

---

Classes are good for object-oriented programming. Having a specific type of object with a specific set of behaviors is useful. Having a specific supertype of object and a number of subtypes that all share the same interface but different implementations is also useful, for having variable functionality without having to write a ton more code and cover edge cases. The three "pillars" of object-oriented design are Encapsulation, Inheritance, and Polymorphism, and while python's success with encapsulation is debatable (by design), it does provide the latter two.

If you don't need those, then classes aren't the right tool for your job. If you're trying to code functionally, relying solely on inputs and outputs without needing to save a persistent state in between, then classes aren't the right tool for your job. It's useful that they're *there*, perhaps, but if you can do what you want with just functions then do it with just functions.

Comment: I'll quibble with the "fail at encapsulation" part. "Encapsulation" doesn't mean that you must make it *impossible* for other code to access internals. It means that there's a public interface other code interacts with that's separate from whatever logic the class may use internally. As long as that separation is clear, for which Python uses `_`, and code doesn't access "for internal use only"-code, encapsulation is fine. The fact that the internals are optionally accessible if you so choose doesn't mean there's *no* encapsulation.